# setting doc head title on jquery address with wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-address

I have a test wordpress blog with Ajax deeplinking. What I'd like to do is simply set a new head title when ajax load page or a post.

either call it by the anchor tag attribute title or hash url name.

Any help would be appreciated.

http://missionandromeda.com/test/ initial test page

```
$("body").append("<img src='loader.gif' id='ajax-loader' style='position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 64%;' />");

var base = 'http://missionandromeda.com/test',
$mainContent = $("#container"),
$ajaxSpinner = $("#ajax-loader"),
$allLinks = $("a"),


$('a:urlInternal').live('click', function(e) {


// Default action (go to link) prevented for comment-related links (which use onclick attributes)
e.preventDefault();

});



$.address.change(function(event) {
    if (event.value) {
        $ajaxSpinner.fadeIn();
        $mainContent
        .empty()
        .load(base + event.value + ' #content', function() {
            $ajaxSpinner.fadeOut();
            $mainContent.fadeIn();
    });
}

var current = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + location.pathname;
    if (base + '/' != current) {
    var diff = current.replace(base, '');
    location = base + '/#' + diff;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will looking for something more dynamic.. here it is anyway

```
$('head title').html(data.match('<title>(.+)</title>')[0].replace('<title>','').replace('</title>',''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Only tested in Firefox yet but it does work over here:

```
$(document).attr('title','Your brand new title here ....');
```